# min-height:100vh causes transparent border to show in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

So I've decided to jump on the diagonal background div bandwagon and have been playing around with a couple of examples and got found a solution I liked which involves creating a triangle.

The problem I'm having is that setting `min-height:100vh` on the body to push the `footer` to the bottom of the page (needed if there is no content on the page) introduces feint lines across the triangle only in chrome (Firefox and edge seem to be fine) presumably this is chrome having trouble with the `border` transparency?

changing `min-height:100vh` to `min-height:400px` will remove the problem but creates another problem that the footer no longer sticks to the bottom.

Has anyone come across this behavior before and knows a way around it?

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/37a09hby/4)

```css
.top {
  background: #eee;
  height: 40px;
  /*this will work like some padding bottom missing  at section */
  border-width: 0px 0px 100px 98.5vw;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #e35050 #eee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  line-height: 0px;
}
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #e35050;
}
.bottom {
  background: #e35050;
  height: 40px;
  /*this will work like some padding bottom missing  at section */
  border-width: 0px 0px 60px 98.5vw;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee #e35050;
  line-height: 0px;
}
#main {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Flexbox? Where is `display: flex` and the flex container? I can only see a lone flex item

Comment: I have now updated the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/37a09hby/4/ applying the `min-height:100vh` to the body causes the lines to appear in chrome but works fine in edge/firefox. I could use a js script to apply the vh but would prefer to avoid

Comment: I would recommend using a different approach for the angled elements, either using SVG or one of these techniques https://viget.com/inspire/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms. I've found that large border triangles can often appear jagged in some browsers.

Comment: Thanks Ted I'll give this a try